# Microsoft ReportViewer Web Control Requiring a ScriptManager

Tags: c#, ajax, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, reportviewer

I'm trying to render the report viewer programmatically within a custom Page placed in an IHttpHandler context

```
ReportViewer rv = new ReportViewer();
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
rds.Name = "Report";
rv.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";

rds.Value = SomeReportObject;

rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
rv.LocalReport.Refresh();

ScriptManager scriptHandler = new ScriptManager();
MyPage p = new MyPage();
p.Controls.Add(scriptHandler);
p.Controls.Add(rv);

using (TextWriter myTextWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myTextWriter))
            {
               p.RenderControl(myWriter);
            }
        }
```

Although I have the ScriptManager added to the page but the runtime complains that the ReportViewer needs one, it throws the following exception at p.RenderControl(myWriter) line

**The Report Viewer Web Control requires a System.Web.UI.ScriptManager on the web form.**

And this is the MyPage Class

```
public class MyPage : Page
{

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        //Empty Method
    }

    public override bool EnableEventValidation
    {
        get { return false; }
        set { /* Do nothing */}
    }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated. This is done on .NET 4 and I'm using ReportViewer 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case just put the instruction

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

in the aspx form source mode and works!!

Answer (score 2):

The error looks like the Form Tag is missing while doing the Rendering. The ScriptManager requires a Form Tag with runat server to perform the Task.

I would suggest to you add all your controls to the Form property of the Page. In Sequence and ScriptManager should be the first control.

I hope this helps.