# MVCReportViewer : The Report Viewer Web Control requires a System.Web.UI.ScriptManager on the web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, reportviewerformvc

There was requirement of reports integration with an MVC application.

I am using MVC Report viewer from code plex
[MVC Report Viewer](https://reportviewerformvc.codeplex.com/)

Initially i was using the rdl file as Server Report, which was hosted on Reports Server. I was able to load the reports.

But the requirements were not to host it as Server Report, instead add the rdl file as a local report and load it during run-time.

I did the code changes as follows to load it as Local Report.

```
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

var dataSet = this.FillDataSet(reportModel.ReportParameters);
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = string.Format(@"{0}Reports\{1}.rdlc", this.Request.MapPath(this.Request.ApplicationPath), reportModel.ReportName);
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DS_Report", dataSet.Tables[0]));
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DS_ChartforSalesRep", dataSet.Tables[0]));

reportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = false;

reportViewer.DataBind();
reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
reportViewer.ReportError += this.OnLoadReportError;

this.ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;
```

Data is loaded and populated into a dataset which is then provided to the report.

I am getting an exception at this line

```
reportViewer.DataBind();
```

Tried to find some help online, and most of them suggested to add scripts tag as below

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Few links 
- [Link 1](http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.in/2015/10/using-webforms-reportviewer-control.html)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795592/microsoft-reportviewer-web-control-requiring-a-scriptmanager)
- [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521984/the-report-viewer-web-control-requires-a-system-web-ui-scriptmanager-on-the-web)

The `ReportViewerWebForm.aspx` which gets added from the nuget package already had the script tag.

But still, it throws the exception `The Report Viewer Web Control requires a System.Web.UI.ScriptManager on the web form`

Edit 1: Content of ReportViewerWebForm.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="ReportViewerWebForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="ReportViewerForMvc.ReportViewerWebForm" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="ReportViewerForMvc" Name="ReportViewerForMvc.Scripts.PostMessage.js" />
                </Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Would be great if someone could help me on this.

Comment: I suggest you to show ASPX page content from `ReportViewerWebForm.aspx` (which bundled with `ReportViewerForMvc`) where `ReportViewer` control takes place. Is the `ReportViewer` instance generated dynamically by code?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Hi, i have updated the question with the contents of ReportViewerWebForm.aspx

Comment: Seems that the ASPX page content is fine atm, hence it may turning into code-behind issues inside `ReportViewerWebForm.aspx.cs`. Have you include `IsPostBack` check on `Page_Load` method?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Its actually an MVC Report Viewer being used in an MVC Application. Don't have code behind file as such. The C# code which i had shared is in a controller which returns the report viewer in view bag

Answer (score 0):

After few days of hit and trial found that the following line itself was an issue.

```
reportViewer.DataBind();
```

Removed the line and things started working fine. It seems, report viewer internally handles data binding. No need to explicitly bind it.